# Cross Product using Math.Net Numerics with C#

Tags: c#, numeric, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I have two vectors `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Generic.Vector<double>`, like the following:

```
Vector<double> v1 = new DenseVector(new double[] { 1, 2, 3 });     
Vector<double> v2 = new DenseVector(new double[] { 3, 2, 1 });
```

I basicly want to CrossProduct them, however couldn't find an official function. I know cross product is a very easy function which I can write myself, but I want to use the API's function.

Both of the below works for me: (Couldn't find such functions in the API.)

```
Vector<double> result = v1.CrossProduct(v2);
Vector<double> result = Vector.CrossProduct(v1,v2);
```

I found this, however couldn't find the function when I tried to write it: [API Reference](http://iridium.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Vector.htm#CrossProduct)

Comment: Are you sure you have the same version of the library that the docs were built from?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're saying. Are you saying you're not sure, or that you *don't* think it's a good question?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sorry. I was checking my version and docs version. I'm not sure my math.net numerics's version yet. I'm checking it. Thanks.

Comment: Wierd. A massive library of numerical functions yet the very basic cross product is missing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the API documentation for *Math.NET Iridium*, which is a discontinued project. The intention was that the *Iridium* code base should be integrated into *Math.NET Numerics*, but it seems that the `CrossProduct` functionality has not been transferred yet, as can be seen in [these](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/discussions/230400/) [two](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/discussions/282397) discussion threads on the *Math.NET Numerics* Codeplex site.

If you want to use *Math.NET* Iridium, where the `CrossProduct` method is surely available, you can download the most recent source code from [here](http://mathnetiridium.codeplex.com/releases/view/16298).

Comment: Hmmm, I see. Do you think switching back to Iridium is a good idea?

Comment: @zagy I have updated my answer with some confirmations that the _Numerics_ library does not yet contain `CrossProduct`. If you can consider writing your own `CrossProduct` method, it is probably better to stick with the _Numerics_ library in the long run, since it is still actively developed.

Comment: 'activley' but still missing that function ... although this is an interesting read maybe explaining why http://www.gamedev.net/topic/181474-4-dimensional-crossproduct/

Comment: By now the method ```Vector3.Cross()``` exists.

Answer (score 7):

Sample method to do the cross-product of a 3 element vector.

```
    using DLA = MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;

    public static DLA.Vector Cross(DLA.Vector left, DLA.Vector right)
    {
        if ((left.Count != 3 || right.Count != 3))
        {
            string message = "Vectors must have a length of 3.";
            throw new Exception(message);
        }
        DLA.Vector result = new DLA.DenseVector(3);
        result[0] = left[1] * right[2] - left[2] * right[1];
        result[1] = -left[0] * right[2] + left[2] * right[0];
        result[2] = left[0] * right[1] - left[1] * right[0];

        return result;
    }
```